# Numpy: Fastest way to clip RGB colours correctly

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Given an 3D array of float RGB pixels with dimensions X, Y, RGB.

```
rgb = array([[[ 1.11204494,  0.17241406,  0.14145795],
              [ 0.98240261,  0.16112416,  0.11333147]],

             [[ 0.1320549 ,  0.11862232,  0.16630839],
              [ 0.10424024,  1.12368929,  0.15233576]]])
```

Pixel 0 and 3 are exceeding the 1.0 limit. The correct clipping is to set the whole Pixel to [1.0,1.0,1,0].

```
rgb = array([[[ 1.0       ,  1.0,         1.0],
              [ 0.98240261,  0.16112416,  0.11333147]],

             [[ 0.1320549,  0.11862232,  0.16630839],
              [ 1.0,        1.0       ,  1.0]]])
```

My way to do this is straight forward:

```
x,y,c = np.where(rgb > 1.0)
rgb[x, y, :] = 1.0
```

Ist there a faster way?

Any help appreciated

Cheers
Volker

Comment: Untimed, but I think you can start with `np.any(rgb,axis=2)` so you don't bother testing all 3 elements if either of the first 2 elements exceed 1.0

Comment: Mark Setchell has a good idea: rgb[np.any(rgb>1,axis=2)]=1.0

Comment: @AlexAlex Thanks for correcting my omission 

Comment: @Mark Setchell, can you write an answer?

Comment: @AlexAlex It's late here in the UK, so please go ahead and write one if you want to. Else I'll do it tomorrow.

Comment: Could you give some indication please of the size of your image - I mean `X` and `Y` - so that my timings are realistic? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `np.any()` idea didn't help much. I also tried with **OpenCV** using `cv2.inRange()` but to no avail.

I guessed at 1080p for your image size (but you can plug in any size) and I guessed around 10% of your pixels might need clipping (by setting the range of random values) and tried some options as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numba
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, prange

def method1(rgb):
   # Original method
   x,y,c = np.where(rgb > 1.0)
   rgb[x, y, :] = 1.0
   return rgb

def method2(rgb):
   # np.any(axis=2) method
   rgb[np.any(rgb>1,axis=2)]=1.0
   return rgb

@jit(nopython=True,parallel=True)
def method3(rgb):
   # Numba
   h, w = rgb.shape[:2]
   for y in prange(h):
      for x in range(w):
         p = rgb[y,x]
         if p[0]>1.0 or p[1]>1.0 or p[2]>1.0:
            rgb[y,x] = [1.0,1.0,1.0]
   return rgb


# Create standard image
X, Y = 1920, 1080
np.random.seed(42)
rgb = np.random.uniform(high=1.1,size=(Y,X,3))

res = method1(rgb)
#res = method2(rgb)
#res = method3(rgb)
```

My timings show **Numba** as a clear winner by a factor of 8-9 times:

```
In [58]: %timeit res = method1(rgb)
16.6 ms ± 129 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [59]: %timeit res = method2(rgb)
24.8 ms ± 1.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [60]: %timeit res = method3(rgb)
1.93 ms ± 21.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you all and especial @Mark Setchell  for your fast answer! I will try numba if it is applicable.
Since you have parallelized, how many CPU-Cores did you use? The code will run on a raspberryPI and there are only four cores. Also I do not know the shares-Memory performance. Also what about the the RAM consumption.

Comment: It should work fine on a Raspberry Pi - you have the code, so just try it with your images. The RAM consumption should be low because it is done in-place - you can measure it with `/usr/bin/time -l script.py`

Comment: You might also try converting to float32 datatype to compare the speed, i.e. `method3(rgb.astype(np.float32))`